# What solutions are there for a Nodejs app control panel?

Tags: node.js, dashboard, controlpanel

Apologies if this should be somewhere else but I was hoping to get some help, I'm currently learning Node whilst building a private project and was wondering what solutions for a control panel/dashboard for the application?

I will be making API requests to check for changes in intervals (the provider does not support sockets) and I would like to log into a dashboard and do things such as change the frequency in which the requests are made. Where would be the best place to start?

Comment: Look for Electronjs

Comment: I just put a little web server into my project on a non-public port and make a little web-ui for controlling things in the server.  Since the admin web server is in the same process, you can just directly change config variables and other internals in your running process.  I don't use any third party stuff for that other than maybe a template engine to assist with serving the control panel UI.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the info! I assume that if I do this would I need to put the configurable settings into a settings config file or can I plug it directly into the Node app?

Comment: You can do either.  The admin web server will be "in-process" so you could directly just change whatever values your live server is using.  Or you could modify a config file and tell your server to re-read the config file.  If you want those settings to persist across a server restart, then you will have to write them to a config file.